# Should I Read K&R Just After a College Course in C?

Tags: c

I just finished a college course in C. The book used was Kochan's. I am tempted to now tackle K&R to deepen my understanding of the language. Theoretically I should already know all the material in it, but I still feel like I would benefit from going through it including doing the exercises.

Any thoughts or feedback?

Thanks.

Comment: "Theoretically I should already know all the material in it, but I still feel like I would benefit from going trough it, including exercises." The more you practice, the better your foundation will be haziz. Tackle it. Even the more if still have a slice of doubt.

Comment: Everyone should read K&R. There are just some things that you get only from reading the book by the person(s) who designed the language.

Comment: Well, if you haven't then do it. No matter when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for reading it. It's a brilliant, concise book, brilliantly written.

Comment: ...and that was meant to be a comment, no answer...corner time, iPhone...